# Control mac from ipad

Tags: ios, macos, bluetooth, mouse

I want to create an application to control the mouse of the Mac through an app,
however I have no idea where to start, I think the best solution would be to connect iPhone/iPad to Mac as a bluethoot mouse, but I'm not sure

I want to control the mouse with the gyroscope of the iPad, I have that part controlled tought.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to familiarize yourself with the [VNC protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing). Then you need to implement this protocol using code in your app. You can check out many of the [open source VNC clients using Objective-C on Github](https://github.com/search?l=Objective-C&nwo=Juniper/contrail-vnc&q=vnc&ref=cmdform&search_target=global&type=Repositories) to get started on code. The last part would be to use the iOS 7 [Core Motion API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CoreMotion_Reference/_index.html) to capture the motion of the device and translate it into a command for your VNC interface.

Comment: But VNC is more for a remote desktop sharing right? I just want to control the mouse